# The equivalent to ToText() in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am converting reports from crystal reports to SSRS.
What is the equivalent to ToText() in SSRS? 
I assume it would be a variation of format(), but I am not sure what it would be.

Here is the original code I want to mover to Sequel Server Reporting Services.

```
else if {rptSurveyDetail;1.QT1} = 1 or {rptSurveyDetail;1.QT1} = 7 then
        ToText({rptSurveyDetail;1.Question1},0,"") 
    else if {rptSurveyDetail;1.QT1} = 2 then
        ToText({rptSurveyDetail;1.Question1},{rptSurveyDetail;1.QP1},"")
    else ""
```

I know this code will not work as an expression in SSRS, but I ONLY am asking what I can do to mimic the ToText() function. Thanks

Comment: Can you post what you've already tried and did not work?

Comment: Can you post some sample data that you are trying to convert and what should be the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

CStr() is the equivalent of ToText() in SSRS